# MySql naming the automatically downloaded CSV file using first and last date

Tags: mysql, sql, select, into-outfile

MySql query gives me data from the `2020-09-21` to `2022-11-02`. I want to save the file as `FieldData_20200921_20221102.csv`.
**Mysql query**

```
SELECT 'datetime','sensor_1','sensor_2'

UNION ALL

SELECT  datetime,sensor_1,sensor_2

FROM `field_schema`.`sensor_table`
INTO OUTFILE "FieldData.csv" 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
;
```

**Present output file:**
Presently I named the file as `FieldData.csv` and it is accordingly giving me the same. But I want the query to automatically append the first and last dates to this file, so, it helps me know the duration of data without having to open it.

**Expected output file**

`FieldData_20200921_20221102.csv`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL's `SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE` syntax accepts only a fixed string literal for the filename, not a variable or an expression.

To make a custom filename, you would have to format the filename yourself and then write dynamic SQL so the filename could be a string literal. But to do that, you first would have to know the minimum and maximum date values in the data set you are dumping.

I hardly ever use `SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE`, because it can only create the outfile on the database server. I usually want the file to be saved on the server where my client application is running, and the database server's filesystem is not accessible to the application.

Both the file naming problem and the filesystem access problem are better solved by avoiding the `SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE` feature, and instead writing to a CSV file using application code. Then you can name the file whatever you want.

Comment: I appreciate your comment. I am curious. What do you use instead of `SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE`, where you can query and save automatically?

Comment: I don't do query and save automatically. I write code in the client application to fetch the result set, and then I write code to write those rows I just fetched to a CSV file. It's not a hard programming task to write an array to a CSV file in a loop.

Comment: I am continually surprised at how much time and effort people who call themselves programmers will spend, trying to avoid writing code. Just write the code for simple tasks like this one, and get the job done.